# Gradle build stopped working after Carbon Black Cloud Threats

Tags: gradle, antivirus

./gradlew clean build doesn't execute after Carbon Black Cloud detected below Threats:

C:\users\xxxxx.gradle\caches\2.4\scripts\build_7fah961hvejaanuen8b3s9661\projectscript\no_buildscript\classes\build_7fah961hvejaanuen8b3s9661$_run_closure2_closure5.class

To remediate cleaned ~/.gradle/caches but that doesn't help.

Also, strangely the folder build_7fah961hvejaanuen8b3s9661 containing threat exploit class gets created all time even after cache is cleared multiple times

[image]

Comment: Had to get a security exception from the firewall admins after which this error stopped happening.